# Why isn't my output returning as expected?

Tags: python, list

So I wrote this code

```
def diagsDownRight(M):
    n = len(M)
    m = [[''] * (n - i - 1) + row + [''] * i for i, row in enumerate(M)]
    return ([''.join(col) for col in zip(*m)]), [''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*m)]
def diagsUpRight(M):
    n = len(M)
    m = [['']*i + row + ['']*(n-i-1) for i, row in enumerate(M)]
    return [''.join(col) for col in zip(*m)], [''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*m)]

def rows(M):
    return ["".join(row) for row in M], ["".join(reversed(row)) for row in M]
def cols(M):
    return ["".join(col) for col in zip(*M)], [''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*M)]
def contains_word(grid: list[list[str]], w: str):
    if w in diagsUpRight(grid):
        return w
    if w in diagsDownRight(grid):
        return w
    if w in rows(grid):
        return w
    if w in cols(grid):
        return w

print(contains_word(grid=[
["r","a","w","b","i","t"],
["x","a","y","z","c","h"],
["p","q","b","e","i","e"],
["t","r","s","b","o","g"],
["u","w","x","v","i","t"],
["n","m","r","w","o","t"]]
, w='raw'))
```

For this code, I want to let contains_word return the word w if it is found in either rows(M), cols(M), diagsDownRight(M), diagsUpRight(grid)but when I put in the code as shown above, the output doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit I tried doing this and still the output returns None

```
def contains_word(grid: list[list[str]], w: str):
    for col in diagsUpRight(grid):
        if w in col:
            return w
    for col in diagsDownRight(grid):
        if w in col:
            return w
    for row in rows(grid):
        if w in row:
            return w
    for col in cols(grid):
        if w in col:
            return w

print(contains_word(grid=[["r","a","w","b","i","t"],
["x","a","y","z","c","h"],
["p","q","b","e","i","e"],
["t","r","s","b","o","g"],
["u","w","x","v","i","t"],
["n","m","r","w","o","t"]]
, w='raw'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Error:-

- In your code every `function` returned `tuples` with 2 lists.
- You iterated within the lists in your second code but the ***returned*** string is `'rawbit'` so you need to iterate through `'rawbit'` to get `'raw'`.

#### Code:-

```py
def diagsDownRight(M):
    n = len(M)
    m = [[''] * (n - i - 1) + row + [''] * i for i, row in enumerate(M)]
    return [''.join(col) for col in zip(*m)]+[''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*m)]

def diagsUpRight(M):
    n = len(M)
    m = [['']*i + row + ['']*(n-i-1) for i, row in enumerate(M)]
    return [''.join(col) for col in zip(*m)]+[''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*m)]

def rows(M):
    return ["".join(row) for row in M]+["".join(reversed(row)) for row in M]

def cols(M):
    return ["".join(col) for col in zip(*M)]+ [''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*M)]

def contains_word(grid: list[list[str]], w: str):
    for words in diagsUpRight(grid):
        if w in words:
            return w
    for words in diagsDownRight(grid):
        if w in words:
            return w
    for words in rows(grid):
        if w in words:
            return w
    for words in cols(grid):
        if w in words:
            return w


print(contains_word(grid=[["r","a","w","b","i","t"],
["x","a","y","z","c","h"],
["p","q","b","e","i","e"],
["t","r","s","b","o","g"],
["u","w","x","v","i","t"],
["n","m","r","w","o","t"]]
, w='raw'))
```

Comment: hey, thank you for ur answer. However, I found that ur code doesn't work for like cols(M), diagsUpRight(M) and diagsDownRight(M). For example, I put w = 'rabbit' which is diagonal as per the grid given.

Comment: It works perfectly fine when `w='rabbit'`. It gives the result.

Comment: What do you get as output when `w='rabbit'?`. As its working perfectly fine for me

Comment: oh nvm. Yea I removed 'return res' thats why. Btw, is it possible to modify ur code without using res, cuz apparently it is built in resources if I'm not wrong. I kinda wanna keep it as basic as possible, so that I myself can understand.

Comment: I edited it. Is it fine?

Comment: yessir, thank u for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

It returns *None* then u have a list of lists,
so you need to iterate over the grid in the contains_word function,
currently you go over a list of lists and this list doenst resolve with your if in condition

Comment: sorry btw, I don't really understand a lot of python related stuff because I'm new. wdym by iterate over the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Your original `rows(M)` function returns a tuple `(['rawbit', 'xayzch', 'pqbeie', 'trsbog', 'uwxvit', 'nmrwot'], ['tibwar', 'hczyax', 'eiebqp ',' gobsrt ',' tivxwu ',' towrmn '])`. To fulfill the condition `if w in rows(grid):` it is necessary that `w` matches one of the lists of the tuple, for example, is the list `['rawbit', 'xayzch', 'pqbeie', 'trsbog', 'uwxvit ',' nmrwot ']`. But since you are looking for the string `raw` this condition will never be met.

In particular, if you change the `rows(M)` function in this way, the result is `raw`

```
def rows(M):
    return ' '.join(''.join(l) for l in M) + ' ' + ' '.join(''.join(reversed(l)) for l in M) # rawbit xayzch pqbeie trsbog uwxvit nmrwot tibwar hczyax eiebqp gobsrt tivxwu towrmn
```

`contains_word` returns:

```
raw
```

Comment: should I add return ' '.join(''.join(l) for l in M) + ' ' + ' '.join(''.join(reversed(l)) for l in M) for every function except contain_words so that if other words are found, that word would be returned??

Comment: this approach is applicable to other functions, taking into account their specifics