# How can I let my code return every string that is available in the grid?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I learnt how to write this code with the help of (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5237560/alain-t) to return all the elements in the list that appear in `grid: list` and here it is.

```
def diagsDownRight(M):
    n = len(M)
    m = [[''] * (n - i - 1) + row + [''] * i for i, row in enumerate(M)]
    return [''.join(col) for col in zip(*m)]+[''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*m)]

def diagsUpRight(M):
    n = len(M)
    m = [['']*i + row + ['']*(n-i-1) for i, row in enumerate(M)]
    return [''.join(col) for col in zip(*m)]+[''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*m)]

def rows(M):
    return ["".join(row) for row in M]+["".join(reversed(row)) for row in M]

def cols(M):
    return ["".join(col) for col in zip(*M)]+ [''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*M)]

def sleuth(grid: list[list[str]], words: list):
    l = []
    for word in words:
        if word in diagsUpRight(grid):
            l.append(word)
        if word in diagsDownRight(grid):
            l.append(word)
        if word in rows(grid):
            l.append(word)
        if word in cols(grid):
            l.append(word)
     return l
```

However, when I run `sleuth(grid, words)` the output returns `None`. What am I doing wrong here?

btw `grid` is the grid of the puzzle

and `words` are the list from where we have to find whether each word occurs in `grid` or not.

For the ones that appear, I want to `return` the word

**Edit** the expected input is `["bog", "moon", "rabbit", "the", "bit", "raw"]` for

```
grid = 
["r","a","w","b","i","t"],
["x","a","y","z","c","h"],
["p","a","b","e","i","e"],
["t","r","s","b","o","g"],
["u","t","x","v","i","t"],
["n","m","r","w","o","t"]]
```

and the output should be

```
["raw", "bit","rabbit", "bog", "the"]
```

Comment: If the `else` never triggers, then the function does not return anything (and therefore returns `None` by default).

Comment: So should I use elif instead?? or a code change is required??

Comment: actually I tried to remove 'else' and still the code returns none

Comment: With this edit, the function has no `return` statement at all... why would you expect it to return something?

Comment: I tried using return, but I guess I'm using it wrongly, cuz it only returns ['rabbit'] while the expected output is ["raw", "bit","rabbit", "bog", "the"].

Comment: Unindent the `return l` statement so it is not inside the for loop.

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried doing that, but my python interpreter returns error. How am I supposed to unindent it then??

Comment: Put it at the same indentation level as the `for` loop.  i.e. if the `for` loop has four spaces in front, then also put four spaces in front of the `return`.  As posted, it has five spaces, not four.

Comment: @JohnGordon I've changed but the problem still remains cuz it only returns ['rabbit'] while the expected output is ["raw", "bit","rabbit", "bog", "the"]

Comment: Like is there something wrong with the code for sleuth(grid,words)

Comment: Yea, when I said 'I wrote this code' I meant the last part, aka sleuth(grid,word). Apologies for that. And this isn't the same question.... its a different problem I'm encountering. Please show if u found any questions that are the same and asked by me....

Comment: You could provide the `grid` with sample in/outputs expected? to make the question easier to follow.

Comment: I have done that alr

Comment: as in I've just edited it just now

Answer (score 0):

`rows()` returns this list of words:

```
['rawbit', 'xayzch', 'pabeie', 'trsbog', 'utxvit', 'nmrwot', 'tibwar', 'hczyax', 'eiebap', 'gobsrt', 'tivxtu', 'towrmn']
```

The exact string `bog` is not present in that list.

You need to check for sub-strings also.

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:-

```py
def sleuth(grid: list[list[str]], list_of_words: list):
    new_list_of_words=[]
    for w in list_of_words:
        for words in diagsUpRight(grid):
            if w in words:
                new_list_of_words.append(w)
        for words in diagsDownRight(grid):
            if w in words:
                new_list_of_words.append(w)
        for words in rows(grid):
            if w in words:
                new_list_of_words.append(w)
        for words in cols(grid):
            if w in words:
                new_list_of_words.append(w)
    return new_list_of_words
print(sleuth(            
[["r","a","w","b","i","t"],
 ["x","a","y","z","c","h"],
 ["p","a","b","e","i","e"],
 ["t","r","s","b","o","g"],
 ["u","t","x","v","i","t"],
 ["n","m","r","w","o","t"]],
 ["bog", "moon", "rabbit", "the", "bit", "raw"]
))
```

#### Output:-

```
['bog', 'rabbit', 'the', 'bit', 'bit', 'raw']
```

#### Next code:-

```py
def contains_word(grid: list[list[str]], w: str):
    for words in diagsUpRight(grid):
        if w in words:
            return w
    for words in diagsDownRight(grid):
        if w in words:
            return w
    for words in rows(grid):
        if w in words:
            return w
    for words in cols(grid):
        if w in words:
            return w
grid=[["r","a","w","b","i","t"],
 ["x","a","y","z","c","h"],
 ["p","a","b","e","i","e"],
 ["t","r","s","b","o","g"],
 ["u","t","x","v","i","t"],
 ["n","m","r","w","o","t"]]
print([contains_word(grid,x) for x in ["bog", "moon", "rabbit", "the", "bit", "raw"] if contains_word(grid,x)!=None])
```

#### Output:-

```
['bog', 'rabbit', 'the', 'bit', 'raw']
```

###### PS:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69871284/16321225 -- Just a bit of logic in my previous answer would work.